# from eventlet.green import urllib2 error

Tags: python, celery, urllib2, eventlet

when I try this code it give me this error . I use python 2.7

```
>>> import eventlet
>>> from eventlet.green import urllib2

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
from eventlet.green import urllib2
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\eventlet-0.14.0-   py2.7.egg\eventlet\green\urllib2.py", line 2, in <module>
from eventlet.green import ftplib
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\eventlet-0.14.0-  py2.7.egg\eventlet\green\ftplib.py", line 5, in <module>
from eventlet.green import socket
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\eventlet-0.14.0- py2.7.egg\eventlet\green\socket.py", line 1, in <module>
import os
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\eventlet-0.14.0-py2.7.egg\eventlet\green\os.py", line 5, in <module>
from eventlet import greenio
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\eventlet-0.14.0- py2.7.egg\eventlet\greenio.py", line 1, in <module>
from eventlet.support import get_errno
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\eventlet-0.14.0-py2.7.egg\eventlet\support\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from eventlet.support import greenlets
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\eventlet-0.14.0-py2.7.egg\eventlet\support\greenlets.py", line 4, in <module>
import greenlet
File "c:\users\abda\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-kkta3f\greenlet-0.4.2-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\greenlet.py", line 7, in <module>
File "c:\users\abda\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-kkta3f\greenlet-0.4.2-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\greenlet.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: DLL load failed: La procédure spécifiée est introuvable.
```

how can  I solve this problem. thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

This is greenlet problem: https://github.com/python-greenlet/greenlet/issues/43

In short, your options:

- update Python to 2.7.4+
- compile greenlet from source
- use other OS in VirtualBox

Comment: linked to specific known greenlet issue